# How to maintain state while adding to Stack in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a State defined like given below:

```
newtype State a = State Stack
data Stack = Active [Maybe Int] | Inactive [Maybe Int]
```

Where the State is a State Stack where each Stack can be either Active or Inactive list of Maybe Ints. Next an empty State is created as given:

```
empty :: State a
empty = State (Active [])
```

Now I want to add an element to the State I tried going:

```
addToStack :: State a -> a -> State a 
addToStack State(Stack element) a = 
   State(Stack element : a)
```

I used the word Stack to perserve the Stack portion of the State, adding an element to the State should not change a State from active to Inactive or vice versa. Is there a better way to do this? Because right now it gives me:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Stack’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```hs
data Stack = Active [Maybe Int] | Inactive [Maybe Int]
```

You are doing two things. First, you are introducing a new *type* called `Stack`. Next you are introducing two new *terms* (ie, values) called `Active` and `Inactive`. These values respectively have types:

```
Active :: [Maybe Int] -> Stack
Inactive :: [Maybe Int] -> Stack
```

Furthermore, these values are "special" in that Haskell knows how to get the `[Maybe Int]` back out of an `Active` value (ie, they are constructors and can be pattern-matched on).

The point is that `Stack` is only a type, not a value, and `Active` and `Inactive` are only values, not types. But when you write:

```
addToStack :: State a -> a -> State a 
addToStack State(Stack element) a = 
   State(Stack element : a)
```

You are saying the following:

- I want to create a function called `addToStack` with type `State a -> a -> State a`. So far so good.
- When `addToStack` is called with a value which matches the pattern `State (Stack element)`, do the following. -- This is not good. Since `Stack` is a type, not a constructor, this makes no sense. It's like trying to pattern match on `String` by doing `f (String x) = ...`. No can do.

What you want is something like the following:

```
addToStack :: State a -> a -> State a 
addToStack State(Active elements) a = ...
addToStack State(Inactive elements) a = ...
```

---

nb. There is a common practice in Haskell called *punning* wherein a constructor is given the same name as its related type, which unfortunately makes this mixup very easy to fall into.